# MySQL Connector/Python as Django Engine?

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-connector-python

Can't find an answer for this even after hours and hours of googling & searching stack overflow. I assure you I've seen all answers that could be deemed relevant and none of those have solved the issue I'm facing. Without further ado -

currently in shell I can do this:

```
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29)
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print get_python_lib()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='test123', host='127.0.0.1', database='mydb')
>>> db
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7fd3a80536d0>
```

verifying that I have this module installed. However when I try to go to the **settings.py** file to set **DATABASE ENGINE** to be

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

and try to start my server i keep getting the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django'
isn't an available database backend.
```

not sure how to fix this. I'm on Django version 1.9.7, Python version shown in code snippet above

What would be the difference between using 'mysql.connector.django' vs. using 'django.db.backends.mysql' ?

Comment: What `mysql.connector` version do you have installed?

Comment: `pip install mysql-connector-django` should help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my successful solution after one day's searching: install the following packages first

```
django==2.2.15
mysql-connector-python==8.0.23
django-mysql==3.9.0
```

Then you can configure in settings file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysqlclient` is the recommending package, however, for some situation we couldn't install the `mysqlclient`

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the difference between using 'mysql.connector.django'
>   vs. using 'django.db.backends.mysql' ?

To begin with the former is the recommended method while the latter is not. The former is fully supported but the latter you need version 1.1.x and there is also a caveat in the django documentation that it may not be fully supported by more recent versions of django.

[MySQL DB API Drivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)

> The Python Database API is described in PEP 249. MySQL has three
>   prominent drivers that implement this API:
>
> MySQLdb is a native driver that has been developed and supported for
>   over a decade by Andy Dustman. mysqlclient is a fork of MySQLdb which
>   notably supports Python 3 and can be used as a drop-in replacement for
>   MySQLdb. **At the time of this writing, this is the recommended choice
>   for using MySQL with Django**. MySQL Connector/Python is a pure Python
>   driver from Oracle that does not require the MySQL client library or
>   any Python modules outside the standard library. All these drivers are
>   thread-safe and provide connection pooling. MySQLdb is the only one
>   not supporting Python 3 currently.
>
> In addition to a DB API driver, Django needs an adapter to access the
>   database drivers from its ORM. Django provides an adapter for
>   MySQLdb/mysqlclient while MySQL Connector/Python includes its own.

Comment: How is the former "fully supported" when I can't even get my Django server to use it?

    `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:     
    'mysql.connector.django'
isn't an available database backend.`

Comment: That is because you have not installed the driver

Comment: @e4c5, 'mysql.connector.django' doesn't work with django 1.11

Comment: @pitchblack408 the question is for django 1.9 from a year ago.